# Brownie AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: brownie, configuration

Hey all I'm learning solidity and I'm following a guide on how to make a lottery smart contract.

At the beginning of the project I'm trying to compile after making a `brownie-config.yaml`

I am met with:

```
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
Brownie v1.16.3 - Python development framework for Ethereum

  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\brownie\_cli\__main__.py", line 64, in main
    importlib.import_module(f"brownie._cli.{cmd}").main()
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\brownie\_cli\compile.py", line 32, in main
    project_path = project.check_for_project(".")
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\brownie\project\main.py", line 544, in check_for_project
    structure_config = _load_project_structure_config(folder)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\brownie\_config.py", line 272, in _load_project_structure_config
    data = _load_config(project_path).get("project_structure", {})
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

I have no idea why it can't find these files. They clearly exist. I am using the latest version of node.js

The script I am working with:

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";

contract Lottery {
    address payable[] public players;
    uint256 public usdEntryFee;
    //AggregatorV3Interface internal ethUsdPriceFeed;

    constructor(address _priceFeedAddress) public {
        usdEntryFee = 50 * (10**18);
        ethUsdPriceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(_priceFeedAddress);
    }

    function enter() public {
        //$50 min
        players.push(msg.sender);
    }

    function getEntranceFee() public view returns (uint256) {}

    function startLottery() public {}

    function endLottery() public {}
}
```

Brownie config:

```yaml
dependencies:
  - smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.1.1
compiler:
  solc:
    remappings:
      - '@chainlink=smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.1.1'
```

Terminal commands:

```sh
brownie init
brownie compile
```

[image: Screenshot of directory]

after letting it sit for a day, I get this error in my terminal instead, not sure what made it become this way:

```
PS C:\Users\black\smartcontract-lottery> brownie compile
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
Brownie v1.16.3 - Python development framework for Ethereum

New compatible solc version available: 0.8.9
Compiling contracts...
  Solc version: 0.8.9
  Optimizer: Enabled  Runs: 200
  EVM Version: Istanbul
CompilerError: solc returned the following errors:

ParserError: Source "C:/Users/black/.brownie/packages/smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.1.1/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol" not found: File not found.
 --> contracts/Lottery.sol:5:1:
  |
5 | import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

PS C:\Users\black\smartcontract-lottery>
```

Comment: Could you edit your question with the command you ran to get this? And also the script you're running?

Comment: All done! thanks for the reply! I'm actually following your Solidity, Blockchain, and Smart Contract Course!

Comment: Hmm... Looks good! Perhaps could you put a screenshot of you directory and from which folder you're running the command?

Comment: okay! done, but it looks like I have a different error now.

Comment: WHat's the new error

Comment: ParserError: Source "C:/Users/black/.brownie/packages/smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.1.1/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol" not found: File not found.

Comment: Can you confirm your config is still the same?

Comment: okay, added a screenshot!
https://imgur.com/a/aICMfqG

Comment: I think at this point I'd recommend restarting from scratch, without copy pasting from this "broken" example. I think you just messed a step somewhere... Should be pretty quick to get back to where you currently are. Once you figure out what you missed, could you update the answer here?

Comment: Okay! I just redid everything up until this, looks like I got the same exact error from when I first posted. It successfully compiles when I delete brownie-config so it's gotta be that.  I know this is a dumb little issue. 

brownie config: https://imgur.com/a/ZVdhuZk
successful compile after config delete: https://imgur.com/hgRiWhK

Comment: so weird... yeah so something is wrong in there. Maybe try `0.2.2` of the chainlink contracts?

Answer (score 1):

fixing indentation on Brownie config: file solved that problem for me

but now i have
this problem:
'dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required'

Comment: it was also indentation problem

Comment: Many issues in ``compiler.py`` or ``_config.py`` reporting ``NoneType`` errors IMHO are related primarily to problems in ``brownie-config.yaml``